# Comando SQL CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, case

Estou tentando selecionar apenas 5 caracteres do campo `description`, tentei de varias formas e não funciona, o comendo que estou dando é este:

```
SELECT description = CASE WHEN LEN(description) > 5 THEN LEFT(description,5) ELSE description END AS description FROM contentphp
```

Qual é o erro que não encontro?
(Estou utilizando MYSQL)

Comment: ao invés de LEN, tentou usar char_lenght()?

Comment: Tentei mas ele diz que não existe esse comando.

Comment: Eu não tenho mysql aqui p/ testar.. :(

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do case, você quer selecionar apenas os 5 primeiros? Tente: "SELECT LEFT(description,5) AS description FROM contentphp"

Comment: Teste aqui (no oracle) e funcionou: SELECT (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(description) > 5 then LEFT('description',5) else 'description ' end) AS description  FROM contentphp;

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante funcionou agora que você postou ele... a diferença é que você colocou o comando entre parêntese.

Comment: Ok, marque como certa a resposta.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, consegui um MySql aqui e testei, deu certo:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(description) > 5 then LEFT(description,8) else description end) AS description  FROM contentphp;
```

Espero ter ajudado!